# read a text in two languages

Tags: language, voice, flashcard

I am looking for software that can read a text in two languages.

The language teacher shares lesson vocabulary in form of semi-structured pdf files.

I tried to copy and paste to murf.ai, (free trial is for 20 min of voice, next it is 15$/month) and you have to mark manually (using dropin) which language/voice to use to each word/sentence, otherwise quality is inferior.

I tried a few chrome apps but fails to read well

I understand that can be done with some solid ai tts cloud, such as aws but seems overkill.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For $20/month you can subscribe to OpenAI ChatGPT Plus. This gives you access to gpt-4 and will enable you to upload and  read in PDFs. Use Plugins / ChatGPT Advanced Data Analysis .  Just tell the AI+Plugin what it should do (in natural language) but include the phrase "without using python" (this is critical).

Presumably, with the ChatGPT App on iPhone/iPad you can get text-to-speech.